# Why is my UV mapping not showing correctly in viewport?

Tags: uv

As you can see in the following picture, the UV mapping seems to be ok in the UV editor, after all I have just used the smart projection with default values, but as you can see in the viewport, something is totally off, and the texture looks like projected sideways for most of the faces.
Never happened to me before.
Keep in mind that before this UV mapping, I used a shader with an external reference object as triplanar projection. But then I removed it, and the shader is now standard.

[image]

In this second image you can see a single face being perfectly mapped, with no overlapping vertexes, but showing wrongly in the viewport.

[image]

Comment: Have you created a second UV map? In that case make sure that the good one is selected

Comment: show also node tree of material

Comment: Hey found the problem: the IMAGE TEXTURE node was set on BOX instead than FLAT. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The **IMAGE TEXTURE** node in the shader was set to **BOX**, due to the fact that earlier on the shader was using a box reference object for mapping.
Changing it back to **FLAT** solved the problem.